# Can anybody explain me why I get this error?

Tags: python, statistics

I am trying to estimate a multivariate probit model using maximum likleihood theory. My limited dependent variable is 'killer_apps' while my explanatory variables are 'score, size, price'. Once I define this equation,

```
def probitlik(beta,y,x1,x2,x3):
      beta1 = beta[0]
      beta2 = beta[1]
      beta3 = beta[2]
      beta4 = beta[3]
      prob = stats.normal.cdf(beta1 + beta2*x1 + beta3*x2 + beta4*x3)
      vlog=y*np.log(prob)+(1-y)*np.log(1-prob)
      loglik=-1*sum(vlog)
      return(loglik)
    
    probitmodel = minimize(probitlik, x0 = np.asarray((0.55,1)),args = (killer_app,size,price,score),method='BFGS')
```

I get this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-816e46276502> in <module>()
      9   return(loglik)
     10 
---> 11 probitmodel = minimize(probitlik, x0 = np.asarray((0.55,1)),args = (killer_app,size,price,score),method='BFGS')

3 frames
<ipython-input-5-816e46276502> in probitlik(beta, y, x1, x2, x3)
      2   beta1 = beta[0]
      3   beta2 = beta[1]
----> 4   beta3 = beta[2]
      5   beta4 = beta[3]
      6   prob = stats.normal.cdf(beta1 + beta2*x1 + beta3*x2 + beta4*x3)

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Print length of you're var beta

Comment: `beta` has only 2 elements.

Comment: How do you say that?